# Java Graphing Libraries for Web Applicattions?

Tags: java, jsp, charts, jfreechart

I've been asked to enhance a JSP Application with (And I quote) "Some Sexy Graphs" I did a quick search on SO and came up with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555804/real-time-java-graph-chart-library) which mentions several graphing solutions, however given that this is a Web application I was wondering if there were any good graphing libraries that can render the graphs client side using JQuery or some such?

Otherwise, has anyone who has used JFreeChart to produce charts for the Web got any pointers.

This is the first time I've done Any JSP (I've done some Java and Have done a bit of ASP.Net) so Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for a graph or a chart library? JFreeChart is great for charts. Touchgraph is great for graphs.

Touchgraph:
[www.touchgraph.com](http://www.touchgraph.com)

Look at this example:
http://www.touchgraph.com/TGGoogleBrowser.html

You could also use google's charting engine:

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/