# Swing high-performance charting library

Tags: java, performance, swing, user-interface, charts

I'm currently looking for a Swing component that will allow me to draw about 5000 points per sequence for at least 3 sequences with an update frequency greater or equal to 100 Hz (and preferably pretty looks).

A clean API is definitely a plus and another plus is the possibility of having two (or more) vertical axes.

The targets are java 6 and 7. Solutions which are not 100% java should support at least Windows 7 and Mac OS X Lion.
Commercial and F/OSS solutions equally welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a bit old but you might find it useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265777/what-is-the-best-open-source-java-charting-library-other-than-jfreechart

Comment: And here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555804/real-time-java-graph-chart-library

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Jide charts](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/charts.htm).

Answer (score 3):

[`JFreeChart`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart/info) can accommodate *model* updates at this frequency, but I'd update the *view* at a lower rate. Five thousand points pushes screen resolution, so a paged approach may be warranted. Support for multiple series is a standard feature.

Comment: The very minimum frequency of view updates acceptable for me is 80Hz (the displays on which this will be used have a refresh rate of at least 120Hz, but 100Hz is really all I need). In terms of points I could cut the requirement by an order of magnitude with some clever tricks, but I'm afraid JFreeChart wouldn't still come anywhere near the performance level required...

Answer (score 1):

[Java2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) is the most flexible solution since you can show what you want at "any frequency".

You have to choose good colors, draw your axes, and here we go !